# Someone knows why the first onClick event doesn't work correctly and the second does?

Tags: javascript

I fell into this problem when trying to create an onClick event seen at the first box and fixed it by creating the second method seen in the second one but I can't see why the first method didn't work, someone has any idea why?

```js
function test() {

  document.body.style.padding = "0";
  document.body.style.margin = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#222";


  let container = document.createElement("div");
  let first_box = document.createElement("div");
  let second_box = document.createElement("div");

  container.appendChild(first_box);
  container.appendChild(second_box);

  document.body.appendChild(container);

  container.style.height = "150px";
  container.style.display = "flex";
  container.style.justifyContent = "center";
  container.style.alignItems = "center";

  first_box.style.height = "50%";
  first_box.style.width = "20%";
  first_box.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  first_box.style.cursor = "pointer";
  first_box.style.marginRight = "2%";

  second_box.style.height = "50%";
  second_box.style.width = "20%";
  second_box.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  second_box.style.cursor = "pointer";

  //onClick event
  let btn1_status = 0;
  let btn2_status = false;

  if (btn1_status === 0) {
    first_box.onclick = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#456";
      btn1_status = 1;
    };
  } else if (btn1_status === 1) {
    first_box.onclick = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
      btn1_status = 0;
    };
  };

  function box2() {
    if (btn2_status === false) {
      second_box.style.backgroundColor = "#654";
      btn2_status = true;
    } else if (btn2_status === true) {
      second_box.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
      btn2_status = false;
    };
  };
  second_box.onclick = function() {
    box2();
  };
};
console.log(test());
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and edit the snippet to add the HTML on which the JavaScript runs, to create a [mre].

Comment: Basically, the `if/else if` is evaluated only once in the first case, and on every click in the second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in `first_box`: as the `test()` function is executend once, it appends only the first event listener, all this part:

```
} else if (btn1_status === 1) {
    first_box.onclick = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
      btn1_status = 0;
    };
  };
```

is actually dead code (supposing the function is run once). Running `test` multiple time will actually add an event listener, creating a great confusion of execution (and also a memory leak).

This is a corrected solution:

```js
function test() {

  document.body.style.padding = "0";
  document.body.style.margin = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#222";


  let container = document.createElement("div");
  let first_box = document.createElement("div");
  let second_box = document.createElement("div");

  container.appendChild(first_box);
  container.appendChild(second_box);

  document.body.appendChild(container);

  container.style.height = "150px";
  container.style.display = "flex";
  container.style.justifyContent = "center";
  container.style.alignItems = "center";

  first_box.style.height = "50%";
  first_box.style.width = "20%";
  first_box.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  first_box.style.cursor = "pointer";
  first_box.style.marginRight = "2%";

  second_box.style.height = "50%";
  second_box.style.width = "20%";
  second_box.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  second_box.style.cursor = "pointer";

  //onClick event
  let btn1_status = 0;
  let btn2_status = false;

  first_box.onclick = function() {
    if (btn1_status === 0) {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#456";
      btn1_status = 1;
    }else if (btn1_status === 1) {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
      btn1_status = 0;
    }
  };

  function box2() {
    if (!btn2_status) {
      second_box.style.backgroundColor = "#654";
      btn2_status = true;
    } else {
      second_box.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
      btn2_status = false;
    };
  };
  second_box.onclick = function() {
    box2();
  };
};
console.log(test());
```